# Commenting out all children of a Panel via Document Outline

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2013

Is there a hotkey or something I'm missing that might allow me to say select an object panel from the Document Outline and comment out it, and all of its subsequent children in one stroke or button press?

Like if you see this in your Document Outline;

Grid
    - Button
    - StackPanel
    - TextBlock
    - Canvas
  (etc, etc, etc, you get the idea..)

Is there a way to select that parent grid, hit a button or something, and it comments out everything for the Grid and its children?

Because that would be pretty damn handy, and I haven't found anything anywhere for it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best I found was right clicking on the highest level control you want commented out in document outline, select "View Source", and use Ctrl K + Ctrl C. Not quite one button, but not too far off. Let me know if that helps you out!

Only problem with this is I'm not sure how to uncomment it using this method because when you comment it out, it removes it from the document outline.

So in your example, right click Grid, choose View Source, and hit Ctrl K + Ctrl C.

Comment: From what I've found that's as good as it's going to get at the moment, cheers!